# Light does not contain `enable`

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class script : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Light m_light;

    void Start()
    {
        m_light = GetComponent <Light> ();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space))
        {
            m_light.enable  = !m_light.enable;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code and when I back in to unity I get this error:

> 'Light' does not contain a definition for 'enable' and no accessible extension method 'enable' accepting a first argument of type 'Light' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error, it's `m_light.enabled` not `m_light.enable`, I don't know what IDE are you using, but I suggest that you change for others one, this kind of thing should be autocompleted and correct by IDE.